# The argument type 'SideTitles' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AxisTitles?'

Tags: fl-chart

[image]

I keep trying using fl_chart. I have problem on y-axis.
I expected it show not only 0. I expect 0~1 y-axis label in this case.

I searched about this and find this code.
https://gist.github.com/imaNNeoFighT/32d8164b1afac5348af0d758853f8376

[image]

Error message is:
The argument type 'SideTitles' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AxisTitles?'.

This is my code: https://github.com/kangsudal/performance_tracker/blob/ddd9f16465801ab704622b577dc2fdb49ebddf1c/lib/widgets/bottomRight.dart#L56

Let me know how to fix and use this well.

Answer (score 1):

I guessed the value is too small, so I changed value from seconds to microseconds.
from:

```
double get seconds => duration.inMicroseconds / 1000000;
```

into:

```
double get seconds => duration.inMicroseconds.toDouble();
```

and Error message: The argument type 'SideTitles' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'AxisTitles?'. was caused by missing AxisTitles().

```
titlesData: FlTitlesData(
  show: true,
  leftTitles: AxisTitles(
    sideTitles: SideTitles(
      showTitles: true,
      getTitlesWidget: leftTitleWidgets,
    ),
  ),
),


Widget leftTitleWidgets(double value, TitleMeta meta) {
  const style = TextStyle();
  String text = value.toString();
  text = text + 'µs';

  return FittedBox(child: Text(text, style: style, textAlign: TextAlign.center), fit: BoxFit.fitWidth, );
}
```